View generated HTML content in preview textarea below the editor with react-quill
I am using the React library react-quill-new which is basically the same as react-quill, just updated.  I just want to view my generated HTML in a textarea below the editor.  I wouldn't think it would be that difficult.  But I haven't been able to find any solid examples online of how to do it.
Here is the code for my Notes Editor:

import ReactQuill from 'react-quill-new';
import 'react-quill-new/dist/quill.snow.css';
import React, {Dispatch} from "react";
import {PriceListType} from "../../../types/frontendTypes";

const modules = {
    toolbar: [
        [{'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false]}],
        ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
        // [{'color': ['#000000', '#FF0000', '#008000', '#0000FF', '#808080']}],
        [{'color': []}],
        [{'font': []}],
        ['clean'],
    ]
};

type NotesEditorProps = { notes: string; updateNotes: Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<PriceListType>>; };
const NotesEditor = React.forwardRef((props: NotesEditorProps, ref) => {
    const {notes, updateNotes} = props;
    console.log({ref});

    const editor = ref?.current ? ref.current?.getEditor() : null;

    return (
        <div>
            <ReactQuill ref={ref} theme={"snow"} modules={modules} placeholder={'notes...'} value={notes}
                        onChange={updateNotes}/>
            {/*<textarea*/}
            {/* className={'form-control mt-1'}*/}
            {/* disabled*/}
            {/* value={editor?.getHTML()}*/}
            {/* // value={notes}*/}
            {/*/>*/}

            <div className={" ql-editor "} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: editor?.getHTML()}}/>
        </div>
    )
});

export default NotesEditor

I've tried multiple things as can be seen in the commented code.
